# What are these network connections?

Tags: iphone, terminal, network

Can someone PLEASE explain this to me?

```
iPhone $ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384 index 1
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
XHC0: flags=0<> mtu 0 index 2
pdp_ip1: flags=8050<POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1428 index 3
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
pdp_ip0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1428 index 4
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    inet 100.127.253.25 --> 100.127.253.25 netmask 0xffffffff 
pdp_ip2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1428 index 5
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
pdp_ip5: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 6
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
pdp_ip3: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 7
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
pdp_ip4: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 8
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
en1: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 9
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 02:00:00:00:00:00 
en2: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 10
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 02:00:00:00:00:00 
ipsec0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 11
ipsec1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 12
ipsec2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 13
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 14
    ether 02:00:00:00:00:00 
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 15
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 02:00:00:00:00:00 
awdl0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 16
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 02:00:00:00:00:00 
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380 index 17
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000 index 18
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 19
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 02:00:00:00:00:00 
iPhone $
```

Comment: `whois 100.127.253.25` might help a little bit.

Comment: 100.127.253.25 is shared address space - likely to be the ISP running CGNAT or something. I've not the foggiest what the rest means;)

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958143/what-are-en0-en1-p2p-and-so-on-that-are-displayed-after-executing-ifconfig) explains what a lof of these connections are.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958143/what-are-en0-en1-p2p-and-so-on-that-are-displayed-after-executing-ifconfig) explains what a lot of these connections are.

Answer (score 1):

The `pdp_ipN` interfaces represent the cellular radios on your iPhone. `pdp_ip0` is currently active and has been assigned an IPv4 address by the cellular network. The rest of the interfaces are pretty standard across macOS/iOS (if you run `ifconfig` on your Mac you'll see many of the same). None of them are currently active.

Is there a specific interface that you're curious about?